# Disable workspaces and windows while in-game

Tags: unity, games, workspaces

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 with Ubuntu Tweak, and I have workspace switching and "show all windows" tied to the bottom corners of the screen. However, I was wondering if there was a way to disable this while I am playing a game; if I'm in-game and move the mouse to either bottom corner, it will either show me all windows or workspaces. This is undesirable when playing a game, and I was wondering if there was any way to disable this temporarily while the system is running a game? Thanks.